# How can I restrict any developer from using my created static library?

Tags: iphone

I have created one static library in iPhone sdk, and I am worried that If I provide code to anyone in which static library is being used, then anyone can use static library. So Is there any way to restrict them by using library until they get license? I am new to licensing any library.

Comment: Simple: Don't distribute the library

Comment: I have to distribute the entire code to client as per NDA and in that code I have used my own library

Comment: I am afraid.. as you have a contract with your client you have to share your library's code also!

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri - The NDA if mutual should block them from sharing your static library with any third party. If you want to block them from using the static library themselves then you must solve that by legal means, write a license agreement. You can not tack on a license agreement retroactively if they already got the library without license.

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri - Or, you could just create some kind of big ugly watermark over all your code (something that you can check for or turns out really ugly results, while still working properly) and then go wild with code obfuscation. But really, this is something that was bound to happen the moment you signed something that forced you to share all your code. A good thing for next time is to write a contract that says that your code from before the contract date does not have to be shared.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a problem you must solve by legal means, not by any technical solution.

Make sure to only give the library to people you trust, and if needed have them sign an agreement not to spread it.

Also ask yourself if it is worth the trouble. Is your code so unique that they can not find it elsewhere, or duplicate it themselves in a few days, using Google and stackoverflow alone?

Comment: This is the only real answer.  Even the big guys (MS, Adobe, etc) have trouble keeping pirates from distributing their software.  The short of it is that once released you have exactly zero control.  Which means your only real protection is through the legal system.

Comment: @PeyloW your advice is really genuine and good, but he is asking for some licensing the library. Means is there any way to do licensing the library?

Comment: @Amit - Licensing is not hard, but a legal, work. Write a license agreement, preferably have a lawyer write it for you. Have the client sign it, then send them the library. If they violate the signed agreement resolve the issue in court if/as needed. At the end of the day it only works if you add the magic ingredient; *trust*.

Answer (score 2):

As said by @PeyloW,

> This is a problem you must solve by legal 
>   means, not by any technical solution.

**But** there are some simple ways to "block the code": You can create a RAR or ZIP archive, encrypted with password, and after they get license, you can tell them the password.

Comment: thanks, but after giving password to them, they can distribute to anyone, right?

Comment: Yes. Then, you should have them sign an agreement, or something.

Comment: hmmmm, thats good idea, but can it be like, even if I provide static library, and as they run on another pc, it wont react. I meant, can I put restriction that, static library can be able to run only on specific PC until I do not give them licence?

Comment: You can make some UUID restrictions but I don't know if it will work on simulators.

Comment: no, I am not looking at device restrictions, I am just looking at PC level restrictions, like if someone run my library on his/her mac OS, it gives error to them, but when I run my library on my mac OS, I can able to run without any hindrance. Device Restriction is not a solution not to use the code.

Comment: I agree that basically this must be done in legaly. But, if you just want to provide demo version before NDA, consider watermarking a certain message over the main graphics surface of the application using the library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "Bind" license to a "developer's computer", than you simply need something that you can bind. For example that can be the emulator's UDID.

you can generate a license for emulator's UDID, and only limit emulator development, while allowing unrestricted access for ARM code (on device)

- so you can basically check for emulator UDID
- check license file
- if license file allows that UDID, run
- if not then show a message etc

for development purposes, everybody needs emulator, so I guess limiting it is enough for you.

Comment: If he ships the code, it's easy to remove the checks. It is probably more hassle to try and protect the lib than to break the protection.

Comment: That's almost the same thing. There are excellent disassembly tools and specialists around. And to remove the check you probably only need a debugger and flip a bit, not understand the whole lib.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create a new static library, check your code coverage and copy in only the code used by the app consuming it.  Or in other words, don't give away more than you need to.

Then, as someone mentioned in the comments, obfuscate the calls. Your library is going to be worthless without documentation if your calls have to be deciphered.  Odds are that anyone that has the aptitude of deciphering what your calls mean probably has 80% of a white-room reverse-engineering of your code already done.

You can't really force a license upon your client at the final hour unless they agree to it. So even if you did try to force them to license your library, it might not even be valid to do so with the original agreement intact.  I'd do damage control to the extent your time is worth and chalk this up as a learning experience.  5 months from now, you'll probably have that static library re-factored to something better anyway.  And next time, you'll work that into your agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the static library, no one can get back the code.

Do you have reservations in others using your static library also?

Comment: Yes, if someone can copy static library and access my static library, I do not want that.